# FATAL EXXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, eclipse, program-entry-point, logcat

I am having an error while trying to run the application. I am new to Android development so i don't have much idea to it.
These are the errors I see in LogCat

```
03-07 11:01:48.210: D/dalvikvm(1407): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 62K, 5% free 2778K/2904K, paused 56ms, total 57ms
03-07 11:01:48.290: I/dalvikvm-heap(1407): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.697MB for 7259056-byte allocation
03-07 11:01:48.430: D/dalvikvm(1407): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 9867K/9996K, paused 136ms, total 136ms
03-07 11:01:49.130: D/AndroidRuntime(1407): Shutting down VM
03-07 11:01:49.130: W/dalvikvm(1407): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a2fba8)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): Process: sp.becomps14.group11.hci.atvm, PID: 1407
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sp.becomps14.group11.hci.atvm/sp.becomps14.group11.hci.atvm.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at sp.becomps14.group11.hci.atvm.MainActivity.init(MainActivity.java:41)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at sp.becomps14.group11.hci.atvm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-07 11:01:49.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1407):     ... 11 more
03-07 11:01:52.710: I/Process(1407): Sending signal. PID: 1407 SIG: 9
```

My code is as follows

```
package sp.becomps14.group11.hci.atvm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int station_no;

    //some declarations here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.station_list);
    init();
}

public void init()
{
    adults=1;
    children=1;
    returnJourney= false;


    // some code here.

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



}
```

I have not even started the implementation properly but i can't get past this error.

Comment: what is  line 41 `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: Stacktrace says it pretty clearly: you have a null reference at MainActivity.java:41. Yes, that line you didn't post.

Comment: add full code of `MainActivity` class with question to get more help

Comment: I suggest you [learn to read stacktraces](http://fr33kk0mpu73r.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/reading-java-exception-stacktraces.html).

Comment: Yes thank you @m0skit0 .
I believe I should have posted the whole code. My Bad. I checked on my code and rectified the error at line 41.

Will definitely go through stacktraces. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I removed the BASIC tag because there's no any relation to this topic and the BASIC programming language giving false-positives on search.

Answer (score 0):

you should clear `adults` and `children` and `returnJourney` variable after `setContentView` method.

`integer adults = 1;
 integer children=1;
 boolean returnJourney= false;`